# Typescript: Typing any key in an object plus reserved keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to implement structure like this:

```js
interface IDataProps {
  [key: string]: ReactNode | ((props: IRenderDataProps) => JSX.Element) // any key except those below
  key: string | number; // reserved key
  children?: IDataProps[] // reserved key
}
```

But i have an error:

TS2411: Property 'children' of type 'IDataProps[]' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ReactNode | ((props: IRenderDataProps) => JSX.Element)'

What I'm trying to do:

```js
type TDataSource = {
  [key: string]: ReactNode | ((props: IRenderDataProps) => JSX.Element); // any key except those below
} & {
  key: string | number; // reserved key
  children?: TDataSource[]; // reserved key
};
```

This option is good, but in deep nesting (level 2 of nesting or more) I get an error:

TS2322: Type '{ key: number; name: () => JSX.Element; children: { key: number; name: () => JSX.Element; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'TDataSource'.

Type '{ key: number; name: () => JSX.Element; children: { key: number; name: () => JSX.Element; }[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: ReactNode | ((props: IRenderDataProps) => Element); }'.

Property 'children' is incompatible with index signature.

Additional clarification: for example, I have 2 reserved properties: `key`, `children` (optional recursive), and I want to have ANY other property that should be `ReactNode | ((props: IRenderDataProps) => JSX.Element)` if it is neither key nor children

```js
const nestingExample: TDataSource[] = [
  {
    key: 5, // I'm required and reserved key
    [`problemIsThatImCustomKeyThatShouldBe-ReactNode | ((props: IRenderDataProps)`]:
      () => <>SomeJSX</>,
    children: [
      {
        key: 6,
        iAmAnotherKey: 'key'
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: @TobiasS. No. This is not helps!!

My key in `[key: string]: ReactNode | ((props: IRenderDataProps) => JSX.Element)`, can by ANY string except those keys:  `key: string | number; // reserved key` and  `children?: IDataProps[] // reserved key`

Comment: This is not currently possible in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) and the answers to the linked questions for more information.